# Oracle SQL query consuming high memory

Tags: java, sql, performance, oracle11g

We are using the below SQL query in one of our application to fetch the top cpu queries in the last 24 hours.But unfortunately we are seeing high memory consumption while executing this query.Can you help me to understand what actually causing the issue.If possible help us with a more optimised query which takes very minimal memory.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
ss.sql_text,
a.sql_id,
SUM(cpu_time_delta),
SUM(disk_reads_delta),
COUNT(*)
FROM
dba_hist_sqlstat a,
dba_hist_snapshot s,
v$sql ss
WHERE
s.snap_id = a.snap_id
AND a.sql_id = ss.sql_id
AND s.begin_interval_time > sysdate - 1
GROUP BY
ss.sql_text,
a.sql_id
ORDER BY
SUM(cpu_time_delta) DESC
)
WHERE
ROWNUM < 20;
```

We have tried with the below query to see any performance improvement but unfortunately didn't help

```
SELECT
ss.sql_text,
a.sql_id,
SUM(cpu_time_delta),
SUM(disk_reads_delta),
COUNT(*)
FROM
dba_hist_sqlstat a,
dba_hist_snapshot s,
v$sql ss
WHERE
a.sql_id IS NOT NULL
AND s.snap_id = a.snap_id
AND a.sql_id = ss.sql_id
AND s.begin_interval_time > sysdate - 1
GROUP BY
ss.sql_text,
a.sql_id
ORDER BY
SUM(cpu_time_delta) DESC
FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Needs more details, like the table structure and any indexes you have. Postgres has a `PLAN` command to have the DB explain what / how a query will be run, check if Oracle has something like it. What are you trying to optimize, memory usage or execution time? [Edit] your question and include all such details. See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert Im looking for a query which could optimize both memory usage and execution time.These are oracle views which stores the performance related data from where we query.

Comment: Generate a SQL Monitoring Report to help tune a long-running query, and post the results in the question. That report will give you actual run times and cardinalities per operation, which will help find out exactly what is running slow and why. First, find the SQL_ID of the slow query: `select sql_id, sql_text from gv$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like lower('%SUM(disk_reads_delta)%');` Next, plug the SQL_ID into this query: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID', type => 'text') from dual;` I'd guess there are old statistics for the tables in the DBA_HIST* views.

Comment: Run this to see how many days of AWR data are retained: `select retention from dba_hist_wr_control;` The default value is 8, and if you extended the range or have a very busy database, the underlying tables may be enormous. Check the table size with this query: `select bytes/1024/1024/1024 from dba_segments where segment_name like 'WRH$_ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY';` And check the execution plan to ensure that partition pruning is only reading the relevant data. (Your query may need to filter by both SNAP_ID and DBID.) On multitenant, you may need to query the root container instead of the PDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ss.sql_text,
    a.sql_id,
    SUM(cpu_time_delta) as sum_cpu_time_delta,
    SUM(disk_reads_delta),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    dba_hist_sqlstat a,
    (SELECT snap_id FROM dba_hist_snapshot WHERE begin_interval_time > sysdate - 1) s,
    v$sql ss
WHERE
a.sql_id IS NOT NULL
    AND s.snap_id = a.snap_id
    AND a.sql_id = ss.sql_id
GROUP BY
ss.sql_text,
a.sql_id
ORDER BY
sum_cpu_time_delta DESC
FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Worth a shot, but with INNER joins the optimizer is usually smart enough to apply the predicates first without forcing the issue with a subquery. An explain plan would clear it up though.

Comment: Additional info : We execute the query every one hour from our application to collect the top cpu consuming queries.We are looking for a query which gives the  data without using many joins of views/tables